# Can I install gcc in iPhone with out jailbreaking it?

Tags: iphone, gcc, installation

Is it possible to install gcc in iPhone (3.0 or above) with out jailbreaking it?
If yes, Do you know a good place where I should start ?(please don't say "Google it!", lol)
If the answer is no.
What is the demerit of jailbraking my iphone? or ipod touch?

I would like to be able to use gcc inside my app ,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install GCC on your iPhone without jailbreaking it. The problem with jailbreaking is that you'll probably void your phone's warranty (provided you have one). Other than that, I've been using jailbroken devices forever now and never experienced any weird issues with them.

Now, if you tell us what you need GCC for inside your iPhone, you'll probably get better answers.

Comment: Jailbreaking does not void the warranty.  Simply un-jailbreak it before servicing (reset in iTunes).  If it's so broken you can't unjailbreak it, Apple can't tell it's jailbroken either.